# How to protect the PDF files in web application

Tags: security, pdf

I want to show the PDF file in some viewer but without stealing the content by users. Is there any opensource viewer to protect the PDF files.

Can anybody suggest me solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent PDF file from downloading and printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing)

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238762/preventing-save-as-in-adobe-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Contents of a PDF or DOC file can be authorized using digital signatures.

You may find out programatic ways to create digital signatures for PDF files

to authorize the content.

I have no further idea.